# left join, with only 1 row per left entry

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

Here's my table structure:

```
persons
-------
id
first_name
last_name


phone_numbers
-------------
id
person_id
number
type
```

Here's my query:

```
SELECT `persons`.`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `number`
FROM `persons`
LEFT JOIN `phone_numbers` ON `persons`.`id` = `phone_numbers`.`person_id`
ORDER BY `last_name` ASC
```

---

This returns all people regardless of whether they have a phone number. Good.

---

The problem starts when a person has more than 1 phone number; I get multiple rows for the same person.

How can I ensure that I only ever get 1 row per person (with the first phone number, or non-at-all - if there aren't any)?

---

**UPDATE:** I forgot to include the fact that I have a `type` column. It's value can be one of three choices:

1. Cell
2. Work
3. Home

First would be determined by that order.

Comment: Which is "*the first phone number*"?

Comment: @eggyal - How could I forget that? I updated my question.

Comment: @MegaHit `type` is a number `1,2,3` or is the description `Cell,Work,Home` ?

Comment: @fthiella - It's not a number (if it were, this would be much easier). It's just text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM phone_numbers NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   person_id,
           ELT(
             MIN(FIELD(type, 'Cell', 'Work', 'Home')),
             'Cell', 'Work', 'Home'
           ) AS type
  FROM     phone_numbers
  GROUP BY person_id
) t JOIN persons ON persons.id = phone_numbers.person_id
```